# Can someone describe me when we use Ulmann and VF2 algorithms ?

Tags: algorithm, graph

When we shall use Ulmann and VF2 algorithms ?
what is exactly the purpose of using these algorithms in Graph theory ?

is it used to describe the sub-graphs inside the main Graph ?

Answer (score 0):

Those algorithms are useful for both **graph-isomorphism** and **subgraph-isomorphism**.

Suppose you have a graph *G=(V,E)* and another graph *G'=(V',E')*.

if *G = G'* (this means there is a correlation between every vertex and edge of *G* in *G'*) then you are in presence of a [**graph-isomorphism** problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism)

If *G > G'* (this means there is a correlation between every vertex and edge of a subgraph of *G* in *G'*) then you are in presence of a [**subgraph-isomorphism** problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem)

VF2 is [known to be faster than Ullmann](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol6/p133-han.pdf).

Here you have the academic papers which depict them:

- [Ullmann](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~vkk06001/GraphIsomorphism/Papers/Ullman_Algorithm.pdf)
- [VF2]: `http://59.108.48.5/intro/leizou/teaching/2012-autumn/papers/part2/VF2%20A%20(sub)Graph%20Isomorphism%20Algorithm%20For%20Matching%20Large%20Graphs.pdf`